# How to set a column to 0 when another column equals 1?

Tags: sql

I want to execute a query that goes through my whole table and sets all the values of the rows X column to be set to 0.0001 if their Y value is set to 0. How would I do this?

Comment: sounds like a simple update query to me.  what part is causing you difficulty?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  But in almost any database the answer is `update . . . where`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Check [ask] for tips on getting the most out of this site.  In this case, it is probably best if you add some source code that you have tried and ask about specific errors that you are encountering in the process; this is a Q&A site, not a code-for-me service.

Comment: @DanBracuk I'm new to SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
UPDATE table SET columnX = '0.0001' WHERE columnY = '0'
```

Comment: You shouldn't include the single quotes.  It suggests that the values are strings, but the question does not have the values quoted.

Comment: Obviously true but this will work either with string and integer, otherwise if they are string it might now work properly

Comment: Thanks. Just what I needed.